# react-redux initial ajax data and generate childrens

Tags: ajax, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to react-redux.I have to says I read a lot of example project, many use webpack and couple a lot of package together without detailed introduction. I also read official example several times, but I still can not understand it well, specially in `how to get initial data, and show it in the dom` and `communicate with ajax`(not like jquery.ajax, use ajax in redux seems very complex, everyone's code has different approach and different style make it much hard to understand)

I decide to build a file manager webui to learn react-redux.
To begin, I just want it work, so no ajax:

containers/App.js:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {getFileList} from '../actions/NodeActions'
import Footer from '../components/Footer';
import TreeNode from '../containers/TreeNode';
import Home from '../containers/Home';


export default class App extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    let nodes = getFileList();
    this.setState({
      nodes: nodes
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { actions } = this.props;
    const { nodes } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="main-app-container">
        <Home />
        <div className="main-app-nav">Simple Redux Boilerplate</div>
        {nodes.map(node =>
          <TreeNode key={node.name} node={node} {...actions}  />
        )}
        <Footer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    test: state.test
  };
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(getFileList, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);
```

actions/NodeActions.js:

```
import { OPEN_NODE, CLOSE_NODE } from '../constants/ActionTypes';

export function openNode() {
  return {
    type: OPEN_NODE
  };
}

export function closeNode() {
  return {
    type: CLOSE_NODE
  };
}

class NodeModel {
    constructor(name, path, type, right) {
        this.name = name;
        this.path = path;
        this.type = type;
        this.right = right;
    }
}

const testNodes = [
  new NodeModel('t1','t1', 'd', '777'),
  new NodeModel('t2','t2', 'd', '447'),
  new NodeModel('t3','t3', 'd', '667'),
]

export function getFileList() {
  return {
    nodes: testNodes
  }
}

export function ansyncGetFileList() {
  return dispatch => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(getFileList());
    }, 1000);
  };
}
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import opener from './TreeNodeReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  opener
});

export default rootReducer;
```

reducers/TreeNodeReducer.js

```
import { OPEN_NODE, CLOSE_NODE } from '../constants/ActionTypes';

const initialState = [
  {
    open: false
  }
]

export default function opener(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case OPEN_NODE:
    return true;
  case CLOSE_NODE:
    return false;
  default:
    return state;
  }
}
```

reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import opener from './TreeNodeReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  opener
});

export default rootReducer;
```

store/store.js(a copy from a redux demo):

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import createLogger from 'redux-logger';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import DevTools from '../containers/DevTools';

const logger = createLogger();

const finalCreateStore = compose(
  // Middleware you want to use in development:
  applyMiddleware(logger, thunk),
  // Required! Enable Redux DevTools with the monitors you chose
  DevTools.instrument()
)(createStore);

module.exports = function configureStore(initialState) {
  const store = finalCreateStore(rootReducer, initialState);

  // Hot reload reducers (requires Webpack or Browserify HMR to be enabled)
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () =>
      store.replaceReducer(require('../reducers'))
    );
  }

  return store;
};
```

chrome console says:`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodes' of null` at `App render() {`

I don't know the es6 well, due to react-redux strange syntax make me read the es6 doc, but I am not sure my code is right.

Tring:

1. I think maybe can not create `testNodes` with `new` instance in the list, so I change `testNodes` to plain json:

   `const testNodes = [
     {name:'t1',type:'t1'},
     {name:'t2',type:'t2'},
     {name:'t3',type:'t3'},
   ]`

   Still same error
2. maybe action can not get the global `testNodes`? I move `testNodes` into `getFileList`, not work too.

I have no idea.
After solve this, I would try to replace `getFileList` content to a ajax call.

PS:My react-route also have strange problem, chrome show blank page and no error when I wrap `App` with route, just feel react-redux is so hard for newbee...this is just some complain...

Comment: can you show us how did you configure store with root reducer?

Comment: @code-jaff I think store and reducer is not much relate to this question, so not put them in order to make a fresh view. Now I add the code to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply

1. you don't need to bindActionCreators yourself
2. you need to use `this.props.getFileList`
3. you don't need to manage it with component's state

for eg.

```
import {ansyncGetFileList} from '../actions/NodeActions'

componentWillMount() {
  // this will update the nodes on state
  this.props.getFileList();  
}

render() {
  // will be re-rendered once store updated
  const {nodes} = this.props;
  // use nodes 
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    nodes: state.nodes
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { getFileList: ansyncGetFileList }
)(App);
```

[Great Example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/real-world)

**Update based on the question update and comment**

1. since your state tree doesn't have a map for nodes you'll need to have it in the state's root or `opener` sub tree.
2. for `async` operation you'll have to modify your thunk action creator
   for eg.

   ```
   export function ansyncGetFileList() {
     return dispatch => {
       setTimeout(() => {
         dispatch({ type: 'NODES_SUCCESS', nodes: getFileList()}); // might need to export the type as constant
       }, 1000);
     };
   }
   ```
3. handle the `NODES_SUCCESS` action type in reducer

   ```
   const initialState = {
       nodes: []
   };
   export default function nodes(state = initialState, action) {
     switch (action.type) {
     // ...
     case 'NODES_SUCCESS':
       let nodes = state.nodes.slice();
       return nodes.concat(action.nodes);
     // ...
     }
   }
   ```
4. use nodes reducer to manage nodes sub tree
   for eg.

   ```
   import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
   import opener from './TreeNodeReducer'
   import nodes from './nodes'

   const rootReducer = combineReducers({
     opener, nodes
   });

   export default rootReducer;
   ```
5. use `mapStateToProps` as above to get the nodes
6. regarding `mapDispatchToProps`

   > The only use case for bindActionCreators is when you want to pass some action creators down to a component that isn’t aware of Redux, and you don’t want to pass dispatch or the Redux store to it.

   Since you already have the access to `dispatch` you can call it directly. Passing a map is a shorthand version of it. [video](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-using-mapdispatchtoprops-shorthand-notation)

Comment: Thank you very much, I never thought that just call `this.props.getFileList();` would fit my purpose! But why I don't need `bindActionCreators`? I see a lot of example use it, and some of them deliver the actions to child node.

Comment: Oh, I understand, `getFileList` in my code is not an `ActionCreater`, so no need to bind.